# BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG - error message missing

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, mingw

I have a problem getting BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG to issue a meaningful error message. I have boiled it down to this:

```
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>

namespace StaticChecks
{
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG( false, "Where is my error message?" );
}
```

The specified error message is nowhere to be seen. Instead I get the following:

```
c:\tryit> x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -O0 -g -m64 -Wall -IC:\boost_1_50_0 -IC:\MinGW-W64\msys\include compiletimechecks.cpp -c -o compiletimechecks.cpp.o
compiletimechecks.cpp:5:5: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>'
compiletimechecks.cpp:5:5: error: template argument 1 is invalid
compiletimechecks.cpp:5:63: error: invalid type in declaration before ';' token
```

I'm on Windows 7 and using GCC/C++ 64-bit:

```
c:\tryit> x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ --version
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ (Built by MinGW-builds project) 4.7.2
```

I get the same error on Linux (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit) using gcc version 4.6.3 and Boost version 1.48.

Also, I should add that when the assertion succeeds, it works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs on [`BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html):

> If the C++0x static_assert feature is not available, `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG(x, msg)` will be treated as `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(x)`.

You're apparently building without `-std=c++0x`, so `static_assert` is not available and the message is thus not displayed.

Comment: +1 that's what I wanted to add, too. But I do recall `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT` showing the message as a name of a `typedef` or an `array` before C++11 (and I can't get it work switching -std=c++0x off). I guess they changed the machinery in recent versions. From the same page: *"For BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(x), the error message will be a stringized version of x".*

Comment: @Angew: Yes, adding the option -std=c++0x makes BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG work as expected. Unfortunately it also opens a Pandora's box of other compilation issues on the project we are working on so for now, we will not use this option. But at least we now know what to do sometime in the future.